# Accepting multi word string from user input and assign to char array

Tags: c

I am trying to accept a multi word string from user input on the console. My code looks like..

```
char fullPath[150];
char fileName[30];
char serviceName[50];
int portNum[6];
char ip[16];

printf("Enter full path where you want the file to be.\nExample: C:\\Users\n");
scanf("%s", fullPath);
CheckDirectory(fullPath);

printf("Enter what you want the file to be named. \nExample: test.exe\n");
scanf("%s", fileName);
CopyNewFile(fullPath, fileName, argv[0]);

printf("Enter RunKey Service Name:\n");
fgets(serviceName,49,stdin);

printf("Enter callback IP:\n");
scanf("%15s", ip);

printf("Enter callback port:\n");
scanf("%5s", portNum);
```

The Issue I run into is...

```
Enter RunKey Service Name:
Enter callback IP:
192.168.100.10
Enter callback port:
443
```

As you can see, it skips over the part where I should input the service name. I have tried using scanf like the other two inputs and I have tried using regex expression (%[^\n]) as well and it does not grab the entire line either.

Edit: After more testing I am able to input into the Service name if I move the printf and scanf above the printf that asks where the file should be.

Comment: Not enough information to answer.

Comment: Is this all there is in the code? Can you post the full code?

Comment: it works for me with I copy it into `int main() {...}`

Comment: Going to add more to the code. But why is the type of portNum wrong? It should only be a 5 digit integer. And length of IP? 111.111.111.111 + Null byte?

Comment: @BrianJarcus.: Post the code - I will answer as a whole instead of writing in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is in the previous input `scanf` the entered `\n` is still in `stdin` - not the `fgets` in the next line consumed it. Put a dummy `getchar()` to get rid of it.

```
printf("Enter what you want the file to be named. \nExample: test.exe\n");
scanf("%s", fileName);
getchar();//<----
```

Another thing is `portNum` is of type `int` -you can't use `%s` format specifier to read into an `int` variable - this is **undefined behavior**. (Not passing the correct type of parameter as demanded by format specifier in `scanf`).

Also you can use `fgets(serviceName,50,stdin);` `fgets` will read it as per it's capacity - no need to limit it yourself.

Another thing is check the return value if `scanf` and `fgets`.

---

To be more clear - when getting string input why use the `scanf` instead of `fgets` - you can use simply `fgets` and get the input into it. Also another point is check the manual for `scanf` and `fgets`. To give you an example of how the return value should be checked for `scanf` and `fgets`.

```
if( scanf("%s", fileName)!= 1){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And in this way also for `fgets`

```
if( fgets(serviceName, 50, stdin) == NULL ){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
}
```

Comment: Ah I see that now. I am still learning C so things like this get past me. Also, what about the size of IP? And your solution solved the issue!

Comment: @BrianJarcus.: There is nothing wrong with `ip`

Comment: ok thanks. That sums up my issue!